# Is the Databricks Operational Security Package enabled by default on Azure Databricks?

Tags: azure-databricks

Is the [Databricks Operational Security Package](https://databricks.com/product/aws-pricing) for enterprise grade security capabilities enabled by default on Azure Databricks or is it an opt-in add-on on the Azure platform that depend on the selected pricing tier?

Answer (score 1):

On Azure security is part of the premium tier. See also [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/databricks/). AAD integration for workspace access is part of all pricing tiers on Azure.